# How to enable deltarpm for dnf package manager in fedora 22?

Tags: fedora, rpm, yum, package-managers

The dnf command downloads the whole package everytime you update it, while yum uses deltarpm and downloads less data.
How do you use dnf as yum to save data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install `deltarpm` package and add `deltarpm=1` to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`? [(source)](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=300950)

Comment: Why isn't this the default anymore? Not everyone has superfast internet to download gigabytes of updates.

Comment: Not sure why, but I know they have problems with certain things, like I know they won't work with Docker images because those have the documentation stripped, so the deltarpms fail.

Comment: With high bandwith connections, saving bandwith becomes less, and less, important.

Comment: Then again, *capped* connections are also on the rise, with more and more people relying on tethered mobile data in many situations (and sometimes getting surprises like automatic unconfirmed updates)... maybe it would be nice if finally NetworkManager's "metered network" flag was accessible from UIs like GNOME and had an effect on package managers, like deferring automatic updates and enabling things like DeltaRPM.